Preventing Retrieval of Deleted Images Using Firebase Admin SDK's getFiles Method
When executing the getFiles method in the Firebase Admin SDK, images deleted through the object lifecycle feature are also retrieved. I do not want to retrieve the deleted images. What should I do in this case?


When executing the getFiles method in the Firebase Admin SDK, images deleted through the object lifecycle feature are also retrieved.

According to the official documentation regarding the getFiles() method, it is said that:

Get File objects for the files currently in the bucket.

So when you call this method, that is the expected behavior, because this is what this method does, is getting files.
If you don't want to get the files and only delete them, then you should directly use deleteFiles() which:

Iterate over the bucket's files, calling file.delete() on each.


I think OP is seeing that files that have already been deleted (because of the object lifecycle policy on the bucket) are still being retrieved by getFiles. I'm not sure that is the expected behavior.

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, puf. I'm looking forward to seeing OP's feedback, so I can update my question accordingly.

Hey there. Did you see my answer and Frank's comment?
